# Is there a way for the user to completely reset an iOS app (delete its userdata etc)?

Tags: ios, reset

I have an iOS app that stores some data in a sqlite database. The app is shipped with a pre-filled database and that database is copied to userdata folder if it doesn't exist and use that for read-writes.

My question is, is it possible to remove/reset an app in a way that the next time it is installed (or run) it is as if the app got installed for the first time? Should I provide it programmatically? Or is the user able to do it somehow?

Comment: The default settings for the app is also not erased when you delete your app.. But I don't know a way to erase that either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the app and reinstalling it will delete the contents of the bundle. All of your data is stored in the bundle so that will reset the app.

You could also perform the reset in the app by copying your "virgin" files over the top of your live files.

Comment: If you misspoke, you should clarify that no user data is stored in the bundle.  Any write-able data is stored in the app's sandbox directory, generally under the Documents directory.  It's not a terribly important distinction for this question but it is a distinction nonetheless.